# exposing all classes and functions visible from the main module

Tags: python

I'm a little confused about the import in a python project.
I used this as a model to create my project:
https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/
at the moment, working in spyder, I set my working directory to MyProject/

```
MyProject
|
|
--- mymodule
|   |
|   |--- myclass1.py (contains def MyClass1 )
|   |
|   |--- myclass2.py (contains def MyClass2 )
|   
|
|--- tests
|    |
|    |-- test_MyClass1.py (contains def TestMyClass1(unittest.TestCase)
|    |
|    |
|    |-- test_MyClass2.py (contains def TestMyClass2(unittest.TestCase)
```

then I run `test_MyClass1.py`
the `test_MyClass1.py` references the `MyClass1` this way:
`from mymodule.myclass1 import MyClass1`
and in the myclass1.py, I reference the `MyClass2` this way:
`from mymodule.myclass2 import MyClass2`

I read about the `__init__.py` and the namespace packages, the more I read the more confused I get...

Basically I do not want to do :

```
mymodule.myfile.myclass
```

but rather:

```
import mymodule as mm
mm.MyClass1
```

or again:

```
from mymodule import *
a = MyClass1()
```

Still, I want one file by class.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import or even https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the import of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` in `mymodule/__init__.py`.

Basically you will have the following files:

```
mymodule/
   __init__.py
   myclass1.py
   myclass2.py
tests/
   test_myclass1.py
   test_myclass2.py
```

where:

- `mymodule/__init__.py` contains the following lines:

```py
from mymodule.myclass1 import MyClass1
from mymodule.myclass2 import MyClass2
```

- `mymodule/myclass1.py` contains `MyClass1` definition
- `mymodule/myclass2.py` contains `MyClass2` definition

Then in `tests/test_myclass1.py` you can import `MyClass1` thanks to:

```py
from mymodule import MyClass1
a = MyClass1()
```

or

```
import mymodule as mm
a = mm.MyClass1()
```

You can do the same for `MyClass2`

Comment: Got completely lost in pandas's init.py but actually pretty simple. Thank you for the clear explanation!